# Is this a Qing costume and did it have a purpose?

Tags: identification, clothing, fashion, medieval-china

According to [this article](https://www.christies.com/features/Chinese-robes-collecting-guide-7813-1.aspx), clothing during was very codified during the Qing dynasty.

Is it reasonable to think this suit may be of Qing dynasty, and if so, what would have been its wearer status and the occasions to wear this robe ?

[image: Possible Qing costume]

### Update :

Just found [this similar looking costume](https://thevintagethimble.tumblr.com/post/48907190042/womans-domestic-semi-formal-coat-chinese-han).  According to the description it may be a woman's domestic semi-formal coat from the late Qing dynasty.

Comment: It's an `ao`, the customary dress of Han Chinese women. The wearer was likely well to do given the quality. Qing clothing is well regulated for government officials and at official events, but this dress would have been everyday dress. Note that by the late Qing Empire Han and Manchurian clothing styles have influenced each other to the point of assimilation. BTW you should always include as much information on a photograh you're trying to identify as possible, including the source, where it is found, etc.

Comment: @Semaphore I believe your comment qualifies for an answer.  Concerning background information, the picture comes from an auction and the description only reads "Summer suit China Qing Dynasty 1900".